# While loop is executing code I don't understand

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

Can anyone please explain how this program works? I have no idea what's going on in the 'while' loop

```
struct L {
int d;
L *p;}

L* l = new L;
l->d = 3;

l->p = new L;
l->p->d = 5; //Is this a substructure?
l->p->p = l;

while(l->d < 7) {
    cout << l->d++ << ' ';
    l = l->p; // ??
}
```

Comment: When posting code, please post a [mcve].

Comment: @JesperJuhl What would you expect in given case? Adding some `int main()` around is trivial, but doesn't add any useful information for the question. The piece of code contains any information necessary to understand the question (especially the definition of the struct), which is not of type *'why is this code not working?'* (*then* we'd indeed need additional information), solely of type *'what is this code doing?'*. I don't feel this kind of question considered [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) either, so what's wrong with?

Comment: @JesperJuhl I couldn't get anything more out of this code because it would be incomprehensible or would have to be guessed (if I had removed the struct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```c
// L is a data structure also known as a linked list. It has:
struct L
{
  int d; // a value
  L *p;  // a pointer to the next element
}

// it creates the first element of the linked list, and assigns it a value of 3
L* l = new L;
l->d = 3;

// then makes it point to a new element, with value 5
l->p = new L;
l->p->d = 5;

// the new element's pointer to the next element is then set to be 
// the first item in the list, hence creating a circular list of 2 elements
// .->| 3 |-->| 5 | -.
// '-----------------'
l->p->p = l;

// then it loops through the list, printing the value of the current element 
// and increasing it to 1 every time, and stopping when the value of the current 
// element is 7 or more
while(l->d < 7) {
    cout << l->d++ << ' '; // prints the value of the current element and increases it
    l = l->p; // moves to the next node
}
```

Here's a very good article that can help you understand what a linked list is and how to properly use it: https://www.learn-c.org/en/Linked_lists

I hope this was clear enough!

Comment: Wow, I get it now. The key was this line `l-> p-> p = l;` Thanks!